# How can I setup iPhone as a wifi hub?

Tags: iphone, wifi, tethering

Good afternoon all, I have a simless ipad and an iphone. My iphone can connect to the internet however the ipad can only connect to the internet using wifi.

I was wondering if there's any way I can setup my iphone as a wifi hub so that The iPad can access the internet through the iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called Personal Hotspot in iOS5.

under the Settings App on iOS, hit the Personal Hotspot section.  If the feature is currently enabled, you will be able to set a Wifi password and turn the Hotspot on.  Instructions on how to connect to the iPhone are built into the page.

The facility is built into iOS, however you will find that it may or may not be available through your carrier.

If you find that the above is not enabled, then you will need to contact your carrier and subscribe to Tethering support for your contract, if it is available, once done you should be able to enable the Personal Hotspot facility inside the Network preferences.

Comment: thanks its working fine :) btw I'ved realised that whenever the network is left alone for some period of time, the hotspot will automatically shut down. is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: @Pacerier it's more than likely a battery saving/3G data saving measure by Apple. First, try making sure your iPhone doesn't go to sleep and see how that works.